# find processes and services and compare them to the base version of these services in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a kind of a baseline machine on which I have run both the "Get-Process" and "Get-Service" cmdlets and saved their output in a file. These are the processes and services that are supposed to be running. What I am interested in is running these same commands again and save their outputs to a different file and then somehow compare these files to find if some new processes or services are running.

I want to find the new processes and services because it can help me identify any malicious activity on the servers. Is there anyway I can compare these and find the new processes and services.

Comment: Are you looking to compare processes and services from a file on the same server over time or compare it with different servers? It is most likely that different servers will be running different processes and services.

Comment: `Compare-Object` should get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: I think the entire proposal raised for the requirement is not an adequate solution. A mere application update could add a new running process, a user opening an application would also show up, an attacker could use a common process name and replace its path, etc. It's also an overhead nightmare to maintain. You will be incredibly reactive to any attack, as by the time you do your manual review, raise the concern with the team that manages the application layer, shut it down, etc, it's probably too late. My advice is to seek a professional solution to deploy on your servers.